# Firefox doesn't play sounds in Slack desktop notifications

Tags: sound, firefox, notification, notify-osd

I'm not getting sounds in desktop notifications, specifically for [Slack](https://slack.com). I've experienced this on multiple hardware.

I ensured I have Notify-OSD installed and have enable desktop notifications in Firefox. I can get sound on sites like YouTube.

Output from Firefox's console when testing the desktop notification:

```
2016/1/13 16:08:47.658 sound is null: been_tree.mp3 window.Audio: function Audio() {
    [native code]
} window.winssb: undefined soundManager.ok(): false soundManager.html5Only: false soundManager.canPlayMIME('audio/mp3'): null
```

System:

```
Firefox 43.0.4
Ubuntu 14.04.1
```

I'm not sure what else to provide, so I'll happily update the information above as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I have script blockers that were preventing the needed Javascript from running right.

White-listing the domain wasn't enough. I had to tweak other settings.

Comment: So what were the settings you tweaked? I need to know too.